# Changing date format from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime

I receive a date from an array in the below format:

```
2014-10-22 07:24:57 EDT
```

I want to convert this to echo only the month and day like this: `Oct 22`

My code below works fine when I'm changing from the `15-Feb-2009` format.

```
<?php

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
$nice_date = $date->format('M j');

echo $nice_date;

?>
```

Here's what I have that doesn't work. Probably not even close.

```
$array_date = '2014-10-22 07:24:57 EDT';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YY-MM-DD HH:II:SS EDT', $array_date);
$nice_date = $date->format('M j');

echo $nice_date;
```

I'm at a loss right now. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't just guess at the format letters.  Read   [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). The format `'2014-10-22 07:24:57 EDT'` corresponds to the PHP format string `'Y-m-d H:i:s e'`.

Comment: This is a standard datetime format, no need to guess it, just use `new DateTime()`, like this [demo](https://eval.in/209704).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to explicitly provide the format, you must provide the correct format.

```
$array_date = '2014-10-22 07:24:57 EDT';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s e', $array_date);
$nice_date = $date->format('M j');
echo $nice_date;
```

Comment: Thanks @ghost I guess i was relatively close considering my skill level. Love this site.

Comment: @Torads if you want more reference, consult on the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), it has the mappings of all of meaning . glad this helped

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "2014-10-22 07:24:57 EDT";

echo date("M d", strtotime($str)); // Oct 22
```

Comment: works well. thanks. i now have options

Answer (score 1):

Try following ( i used `date` and `strtotime` ) :

```
$originalDate = "2014-10-22 07:24:57 EDT";
$newDate = date("M j", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate;
```

Answer (score -1):

`$array_date = '2014-10-22 07:24:57 EDT';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YY-MM-DD HH:II:SS EDT', $array_date);
$nice_date = date('M d',$date);
echo $nice_date;`

Comment: When I use this it gives me Jan 01?

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8jfb-iv6t